# Find columns with headers that vary from one column to the next

Tags: excel, vba

Want to process an excel spreadsheet, many columns, using a vba macro.  Within the spreadsheet the columns have headers denoting a property, such as “P.#”, where # starts at 1 and goes to a higher value which can vary from one spreadsheet to another.

For example, the following spreadsheet table:

```
Excel column    --- U   V   W   --- AX  AY  ---
headers         --- T.1 P.1 C.1     T.2 P.2 ---
date            --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
```

I want to pick up the P.# columns and copy them to another spreadsheet.  I know how to copy from one spreadsheet to another, my problem is picking up the P columns as the # changes and copy the column to another spreadsheet (same workbook).  I'm wrapped around the axle on this!!

Comment: What did you already try?  You should be able to use `If headerCell.Value Like "P.#" Or headerCell.Value Like "P.##"` for example to match "P." followed by one or two digits.

Comment: Thank you for your reply/question Tim! I have used Set aCell = .Range("A2:OZ2").Find(What:="P.", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _ MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) That didn't work. I have changed "P." to a particular #, e.g. "P.1" or "P.2" etc and that works fine but any general characteristic as you suggest didn't work. Certainly could be my lack of experience causing the problem.

Comment: `LookAt:=xlWhole` >> `LookAt:=xlPart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was suggesting:

```
Dim c As Range, v

For Each c In Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.Rows(2), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    v = Trim(c.Value)
    If v Like "P.#" Or v Like "P.##" Then
        Debug.Print v & " found at " & c.Address & _
                     " on '" & c.Parent.Name & "'"
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked fine except for one issue that resulted from the software generating the spreadsheet which put a space in front of the P.  Changing the "P.#" to " P.#" etc fixed that.  No way you would have ever known about that!

Comment: You can allow for that by removing any leading/trailing spaces using Trim() - see edits above

Comment: yes, see you slightly revised to trim the c.value